# Bluetooth gets ON by itself in every session

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I don't know what is wrong. I use 18.04, every time when I boots into my laptop Ubuntu, I find that Bluetooth is ON. I turn it off and it stays so till I switch off my laptop. But when I boots into Ubuntu again Bluetooth is ON. No matter how many time I turn it off, it comes back with every new session. Is there any way to permanently turn it off ?

Comment: That might work for me. But my question is different. Shouldn't it be left off when I switch it off once ? Or is it supposed to come back in every session ?

Comment: It should be left off. What about wifi? Should it be left off when we switch it off once? Maybe the developers were thinking along this line. I am not so sure now.

Comment: I see. But why should someone force users to be online ( wifi ) if they do not wish to ?